# $.post() jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Here is a piece of code :

```
$username="anant";
$name="ana";
echo $username;
echo $name;
```

Now if using jquery $.post() i want to retrieve $username and $name ,how would I do it ?

Thanks!

Comment: With great difficulty, since the value you would get back from an HTTP request would be `auantana` and you would have no way of knowing where one variable ended and the next began. Is that really the data you have? What is the problem you are having? What have you tried, how did the result differ from what you expected?

Comment: that was just a piece of code!! post some meaningful code. how and where you use $.post.? from where you want to retriev?

Comment: suppose the file(PHP) is named test.php
and i want to retrieve these variables using $.post("test.php",function(data){}) , then how would i use "data",the returned variable , if possible to separate the data ?

Comment: As David already said, you need to distinguish the two variables. You can use something simple like a : character (provided users can't have : chars in their name), or you could use XML (the correct way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a php expert but try something like:

php

```
$username="anant";
$name="ana";
echo json_encode(array("username"=>$username,"name"=>$name));
```

js

```
$(function() {
  $.get('test.php', function(data) {
     alert(data.username + ':' + data.name);
  });
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

I assume the code is your php based response to the `$.post` call. If all you are returning are values then the easiest thing to do is to return a json response. For example...

PHP Script:

```
$values = array(
  'username' => 'anant'
  'name' => 'ana'
);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($values);
```

JS `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax(
  url: '/path/to/script.php',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
     alert('Username: '+data.username);
     alert('name: '+data.name);
  }
);
```

Or if you wanna stick with `$.post` then follow kovshenin's answer for the syntax using `$.post`. But be sure you use my php code witht he `header()` call to properly set the content type of the http response. I just prefer to use the long hand.

Answer (score 1):

You will be better off with json_encode which javascript will understand just fine:

```
$res = array('username' => 'anant', 'name' => 'something'); 
echo json_encode($res);
```

Then use the following code in jQuery to retrieve the values:

```
$.post('/something', function(response) {
    alert("Username is: " + response.username + " and name is: " + response.name);
}, "json");
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I know what you are trying to do post expects a fourth parameter the encoding type. If you set it to JSON you would encode your data like so

```
echo '{"username": ".'$username.'", name":"'.$name.'"}'; //Json may not be perfect
```

you can access it in jQuery using

```
data.username
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you have to do a `GET` not a `POST`. You may need to change your server side code a little bit so that front end had a clue of how to identify different values (JSON will be better) but a simple `,` should work fine.

```
$username="anant";
$name="ana";
echo "$username,"
echo "$name";
```

your output will be then something like `Anant001,Anant` your `username, name`.

Then use a simple jQuery call to get it and split it by `,` and here is an example..

```
$.get('/getnames', function(data){
     var tokens = data.split(",");
     var username = tokens[0];
     var name = tokens[1];
});
```

Comment: Last I checked, PHP strings needed to be quoted. `echo $username . ",";` or `echo "$username,";`